# Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) Error List

Tags: mef

I am using Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) in Visual Studio 2010 to enhance Visual Studio itself.  Specifically, I am generating errors in certain situations to help the developer know when something is wrong with the code.  I'm able to get the red squiggly to appear using the ErrorTag, but the error doesn't appear within the error list.

I noticed that when the custom errors are present, the application still runs.  So the custom errors don't actually prevent the developer from ignoring them and going on their merry way.  In essence, from what I can tell, all the ErrorTag really does is create a red squiggly and that's it.

Does anyone know how to add an error to the error list using MEF and prevent the application from running if custom errors are present?  It sort of defeats the purpose of creating errors if it's not actually highlighted to the developer other than staring straight at it.  Below are the code snippets.  These are only looking for a simply text to tag as an error just to keep the example simple and clean.

Also, does anyone have any good videos or books regarding extending visual studio?  The best I've found is on Pluralsight, but it still only scratches the surface.

```
[Export(typeof(ITaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("code")]
[TagType(typeof(ErrorTag))]
class CheckTextErrorProvider : ITaggerProvider
{
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        if (buffer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Buffer is null");

        }
        else
        {
            return new CheckTextErrorTagger() as ITagger<T>;
        }
    }
}


class CheckTextErrorTagger: ITagger<IErrorTag>
{
    private const string _searchText = "checktext";
    public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IErrorTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        foreach (SnapshotSpan currSpan in spans)
        {
            int loc = currSpan.GetText().ToLower().IndexOf(_searchText);

            if (loc > -1)
            {
                SnapshotSpan CheckTextSpan = new SnapshotSpan(currSpan.Snapshot, new Span(currSpan.Start + loc, _searchText.Length));
                yield return new TagSpan<ErrorTag>(CheckTextSpan, new ErrorTag());
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

Comment: try [creating a custom MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163589.aspx) which you should be able to use to spit out errors and such (to the Errors window)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an ErrorListProvider:

```
 class ErrorListHelper
{
    public static ErrorListProvider GetErrorListProvider()
    {


        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider globalService = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider));

        System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider(globalService);

        ErrorListProvider mErrorListProvider = new ErrorListProvider(serviceProvider);
        mErrorListProvider.ProviderName = "JS Errors";
        mErrorListProvider.ProviderGuid = new Guid(EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindCode);
        return mErrorListProvider;
    }
}
```

use it:

```
mErrorListProvider = ErrorListHelper.GetErrorListProvider();
```

and add an error:

```
ErrorTask errorTask = new ErrorTask();

            errorTask.Line = err.LineIndex;
            errorTask.Column = err.ColumnIndex;
            errorTask.Text = err.Text;
            errorTask.ErrorCategory = TaskErrorCategory.Warning;
            errorTask.Document = mFilePath;

            errorTask.Navigate += errorTask_Navigate;

            mErrorListProvider.Tasks.Add(errorTask);
```